# Unable to query null in datetime column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[select query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcIdx.png)

There are are many entries having NUll as ShippedDate, one of them can be seen in the photo, but when i search for those entries where ShippedDate is NULL is get a empty set.

**How do i select all having NULL as ShippedDate**

Comment: Compare with NULL value cannot be performed using equal operator `=` - in will give FALSE always. Use `WHERE field IS NULL` or null-safe compare `WHERE field <=> NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong operator, equal not work with null

```
... WHERE ShippedDate is NULL
```